# "missing return statement", but I know it is there

Tags: c++

Assume I have the following function:

```
// Precondition:  foo is '0' or 'MAGIC_NUMBER_4711'
// Returns:       -1 if foo is '0'
//                 1 if foo is 'MAGIC_NUMBER_4711'
int transmogrify(int foo) {
    if (foo == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (foo == MAGIC_NUMBER_4711) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains "missing return statement", but I know that `foo` never has different values than `0` or `MAGIC_NUMBER_4711`, or else my function shall have no defined semantics.

What are preferable solutions to this? 
Is this really an issue, i.e. what does the standard say?

Comment: And even though I answered this myself, I'll hold still for more solutions and the obligatory standards reference.

Comment: ".. I know that foo never has different values than 0 or MAGIC_NUMBER_4711." I can't tell that from the code you posted. Why would you expect the compiler to be able to?

Comment: @Fred: he doesn't expect the compiler to be able to do that, he just doesn't want it to issue a warning for correct code.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I suppose it's "correct code" in the sense of "standards-conforming, but gives undefined behavior if it's ever given different input than you expect."

Comment: @Fred: exactly, it's "correct" in the same sense that the implementation of `strlen` in glibc is "correct": some inputs result in undefined behavior, and those inputs are known to the programmer (via documentation). Depending on the project that may or may not be "correct enough", but often it is.

Comment: @FredLarson: I refined the code.

Comment: Is MAGIC_NUMBER_4711 an enum or define?

Comment: @0A0D: This question is agnostic to this. It focuses more on the general case where _some_ code yields this diagnostic, the posted code is just exemplary :)

Comment: @phresnel: Are you sure?

Comment: @0A0D: The example could also be some math function with well-defined semantics for some input, but undefined for others. Imagine a square-rootfinder that won't work well on negative numbers.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Sorry for the late comment. In this case, just upgrading the compiler would even "increase" the problem. I am looking for ways to solve the problem were the function fulfills its contract (and has no defined behaviour for foul input), but where there is still a possibility of caller's getting it wrong.

Comment: IMHO The semantically correct solution is an other else throwing a `ParameterIsNoMagicNumber` exception.

Comment: @mg30rg: But then the function has the burden of not being able to be `nothrow`

Comment: @phresnel In that case a wrapper function is required (something like `transmogrifynothrow()`) which calls `transmogrify()` and swallows the exception.

Comment: @mg30rg: Yes, every problem can be solved with one more indirection ;) But more seriously, the accepted answer actually contains a throw. I consider this a valid solution, except for the nothrow-case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes, your compiler is not able to deduce that your function actually has *no* missing return. In such cases, several solutions exist:

Assume the following simplified code (though modern compilers will see that there is no path leak, just exemplary):

```
if (foo == 0) {
    return bar;
} else {
    return frob;
}
```

### Restructure your code

```
if (foo == 0) {
    return bar;
}
return frob;
```

This works good if you can interpret the if-statement as a kind of firewall or precondition.

### abort()

```
if (foo == 0) {
    return bar;
} else {
    return frob;
}
abort(); return -1; // unreachable
```

Return something else accordingly. The comment tells fellow programmers and yourself why this is there.

### throw

```
#include <stdexcept>

if (foo == 0) {
    return bar;
} else {
    return frob;
}

throw std::runtime_error ("impossible");
```

### Disadvantages of Single Function Exit Point

#### flow of control control

Some fall back to [one-return-per-function a.k.a. single-function-exit-point](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleFunctionExitPoint) as a workaround. This might be seen as obsolete in C++ because you almost never know where the function will really exit:

```
void foo(int&);

int bar () {
    int ret = -1;
    foo (ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Looks nice and looks like SFEP, but reverse engineering the 3rd party proprietary `libfoo` reveals:

```
void foo (int &) {
    if (rand()%2) throw ":P";
}
```

This argument does not hold true if `bar()` is `nothrow` and so can only call `nothrow` functions.

#### complexity

Every mutable variable increases the complexity of your code and puts a higher burden on the cerebral capacity on your code's maintainer. It means more code and more state to test and verify, in turn means that you suck off more state from the maintainers brain, in turn means less maintainer's brain capacity left for the important stuff.

#### missing default constructor

Some classes have no default construction and you would have to write really bogus code, if possible at all:

```
File mogrify() {
    File f ("/dev/random"); // need bogus init because it requires readable stream
    ...
}
```

That's quite a hack just to get it declared.

Comment: "*Sometimes, your compiler is not able to deduce that your function actually has no missing return*" ...Which compiler are you using then? To me, the best solution is to change (and update) the compiler.

Comment: Does the obvious `return (foo == 0) ? -1 : 1;` fall foul of your "never use SFEP" policy? Anyway, when `transmogrify` is itself documented a nothrow function (and the return type is cheap to construct) then the problem you describe isn't applicable and so "obsolete in C++" seems false.

Comment: Broken compilers that issue spurious and incorrect warnings, while reasonably common, are not a good reason to convolute your code and make it harder to read.

Comment: @Steve: Nope. I'll try to refine my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think the remark is just slightly misphrased -- the function in fact does have a missing return, but the path on which that missing return fails to occur is unreachable, and the compiler need not notice that. This particular example might be so trivial to detect that you consider a compiler that doesn't detect it to be faulty, in which case construct another example more to your taste. Consider `for (int i = 38; i < 42; ++i) if (isprime(i)) return 0;`. There's no "missing return" any more than in the questioner's code, since 41 is prime, but I don't expect my compiler to know that.

Comment: @Chris: I have updated the question to reflect that the compiler might have a hard or impossible time proving the correctness.

Comment: "this can imply an unnecessary performance loss" and "never optimize without measuring" are somewhat contradictory. If it is incorrect to optimize without measuring, then it is incorrect to rule out a particular way of writing the code just because it might be slower. So the remark about performance loss is at best irrelevant to the decision at hand, and at worst misleading.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You are right. I have fallen prey of premature pessimization there.

Comment: @phresnel: I do agree though that initializing an object to a value that will never be used, especially the bogus initialization of that `File` object, muddies up the code for the reader quite aside from any performance issues there may be.

Comment: Your alternatives to SESE all look like strong arguments for it:-).  In the case in question, I'd use a separate `assert` that the input is one of the two legal values, and a `?` operator in the `return`.  Simple, elegant, and easy to analyse.

Answer (score 2):

In C89 and in C99, the return statement is never required. Even if it is a function that has a return different than `void`.

C99 only says:

> (C99, 6.9.1p12 "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."

In C++11, the Standard says:

> (C++11, 6.6.3p2) "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function"

Comment: Very interesting note, thanks. But I am afraid that this question is about C++.

Comment: @phresnel it had the C tag, but it has since been removed.

Comment: @phresnel: It is the same for C++, "falling out" of a function is UB.

Comment: @PlasmaHH there is actually a slight difference if you read the C++ quote: in C you also have to use the value to invoke UB while in C++ just reaching the `}` is UB.

Comment: @ouah: I am sorry, it hadn't the C-tag. But after the edit, let me ++vote.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you can tell that the input will only have one of two values doesn't mean the compiler can, so it's expected that it will generate such a warning.

You have a couple options for helping the compiler figure this out.

- You could use an enumerated type for which the two values are the only valid enumerated values. Then the compiler can tell immediately that one of the two branches has to execute and there's no missing return.
- You could `abort` at the end of the function.
- You could `throw` an appropriate exception at the end of the function.

Note that the latter two options are better than silencing the warning because it predictably shows you when the pre-conditions are violated rather than allowing undefined behavior. Since the function takes an `int` and not a class or enumerated type, it's only a matter of time before someone calls it with a value other than the two allowed values and you want to catch those as early in the development cycle as possible rather than pushing them off as undefined behavior because it violated the function's requirements.

Comment: Usually I strive for hard-to-get-wrong code, too. Question code was just exemplary, but really good points on the preconditions, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the compiler is doing exactly what it should.

```
int transmogrify(int foo) {
    if (foo == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (foo == MAGIC_NUMBER_4711) {
        return 1;
    }
    // you know you shouldn't get here, but the compiler has
    // NO WAY of knowing that.  In addition, you are putting
    // great potential for the caller to create a nice bug.
    // Why don't you catch the error using an ELSE clause?
    else {
        error( "transmorgify had invalid value %d", foo ) ;
        return 0 ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: That is of course true, but I am afraid the non-code part as well as the comment part in the code of your answer is not an answer to the question (which was "what do you do in such case?", rather than "why does the compiler warn me?" or "how to make the compiler shut up"). My personal opinion is that you shouldn't return anything in case of a runtime- or logic-error, at least if the code ought to be a general solution applicable to general types (what if you return a system resource? then you move your error to the caller site). Or is your error-function a program-end-point?